# How to join three table if one key value should be or should not be in a table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to design an app, In which i want to fetch the values in a 
either or condition using query, 
I have three tables: text,image,audio in each table complaint_id column is same.

Note: the record get inserted in a table text is compulsory.

but in the case of image and audio it may or may not insert a record 
(because it depend on user whether to insert image or audio)

table: text

```
complaint_id | text_note
------------------------
   34556     | Hello
   34557     | welcome
```

table: image

```
complaint_id | photo_link
-----------------------------
   34556     | photo_link
```

table: audio

```
complaint_id | audio_link
----------------------------
   34557     | audio_link
```

I want output as

```
complaint_id | text_note | photo_link     | audio_link
------------- ----------- ---------------- --------------
34556        |  Hello    | photo_link     |
34557        |  welcome  |                | audio_link
```

I have designed one query but it doesn't wok for me!

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    test t
JOIN image i ON (
    t.complaint_id = i.complaint_id
)
JOIN audio a ON (
    t.complaint_id = a.complaint_id
)
GROUP BY
    t.complaint_id
```

Comment: left join image .... left join audio a

Comment: can you have multiple images or multiple audio files for a complaint?

Comment: No...! one complaint carry one image or one audio or no image no audio but text is compulsory

Comment: @artm I just use left join but is this work for image and audio values going blank? can u please elaborate in actual answer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT
    complaint_id,
    IFNULL(text_note, '') text_note,
    IFNULL(photo_link, '') photo_link,
    IFNULL(audio_link, '') audio_link
FROM
    text
LEFT OUTER JOIN image ON text.complaint_id = image.complaint_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN audio ON text.complaint_id = audio.complaint_id
```

Comment: thanks bro! it works for me....but one issue is that it gives 'NULL' in an application but  i want as ' ' (i.e blank).

Comment: this answer will not work in one condition like if text table doesn't have any one records of audio table or image table.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    COALESCE (
        i.complaint_id,
        t.complaint_id,
        a.complaint_id
    ) complaint_id,
    t.text_note,
    i.photo_link,
    a.audio_link
FROM
    [ text ] t
FULL JOIN [ image ] i ON i.complaint_id = t.complaint_id
FULL JOIN audio_link a ON a.complaint_id = t.complaint_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Well i made up this query in oracle and it works fine !

```
SELECT
    a.complaint_id,
    a.text_note,
    b.photo_link,
    c.audio_link
FROM
    text a
LEFT OUTER JOIN image b ON a.complaint_id = b.complaint_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN audio c ON a.complaint_id = c.complaint_id
```

Thumbs up if it works for you.
Thanks.

Comment: use select a.complaint_id,a.text_note,nvl(b.photo_link,' '),nvl(c.audio_link,' ')
from text a left outer join image b
on a.complaint_id = b.complaint_id
left outer join audio c
on a.complaint_id = c.complaint_id to show blank values instead of null

Comment: It gives "FUCTION .nvl not exist"

Comment: @RushiK As you are using MySQL i think IFNULL() shall work for you. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
select t.Complaint_id,t.text_note,i.Photo_link,a.audio_link
from text t 
left join image i on t.compalint_id=i.complaint_id 
left join audio a on t.compalint_id=a.complaint_id
```

Comment: Please add brief description to your answer explaining how it would work.